# Replacing all ampersand character in query string

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

I need help for rewriting URL as I need to concatenate all the query string values to a single parameter concatenated with + sign and replacing = sign with :

So a link like this

```
http://domain.com/mypage?p1=v1&p2=v2&p3=v3
```

would become

```
http://domain.com/mypage?params=p1:v1+p2:v2+p3:v3
```

(Edited: I change the page name, removing .php)

Comment: It is possible but it would be more efficient to do it with PHP. Why would you want to use htaccess and `mod_rewrite` for that ?

Comment: The page is not actually in PHP, I used this name as an example. I need to use a library that I cannot change.

Comment: Are p1, p2, p3 fixed (ala are they always named like that)? And are they all required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the query string will not have a fixed number/name parameters, I decided to write a CGI script to do the transformation and then redirecting to the modified url.

Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this problem is not best solved via mod_rewrite. If you can, you should modify the receiving end (which you can't) or modify the sending end (which you might be able to) to send the proper data instead. If you happen to know all parameter names that can possibly appear in the url, you can use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784942/reference-capture-groups-of-multiple-rewritecond-in-rewriterule) instead.

You can match the query string with the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable in a `RewriteCond`. You then internally rewrite to an url with that query string.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !params=
RewriteRule ^sillyframework/sillypage$ sillyframework/sillypage?%{QUERY_STRING}&params=

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&=]+)=([^&]+)&params=([^&=]*)$
RewriteRule ^sillyframework/sillypage$ sillyframework/sillypage?params=%3+%1:%2 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&=]+)=([^&]+)&(.*)&params=([^&=]*)$
RewriteRule ^sillyframework/sillypage$ sillyframework/sillypage?%3&params=%4+%1:%2 [L]
```

There is one problem with this approach, and that it requires several internal recursions to translate all parameters in the query string. Why is this bad? Every recursion costs time. To protect the server, the default amount of recursions allowed is 10, after which you'll get an internal server error. It is possible to bypass this recursion limit, either by increasing the limit, or by using the `[N]` flag. The `[N]` flag is a very bad idea, just as much as a badly chosen limit for the recursion limit. Apache will not terminate in incorrect rule with the N flag, so a specially crafted request for a rule that uses it can let mod_rewrite dos your own server. A badly chosen (high value) of InternalRecursionLimit basically does the same. Instead of showing an internal server error, mod_rewrite will blow up the server before it hits that limit. The difference between the `N` flag and the limit is that a high value for `InternalRecursionLimit` and `L` will theoretically eventually hit that limit, where `N` will not do that.

Comment: Please be adviced that I haven't tested these rules yet, as I do not have access to an Apache server from this realm. If I didn't mess it up completely it should work. If it didn't work, try adding the `DPI` flag. If it still doesn't work, blame someone else, not me. Also: The framework does not necessarily need to be silly for this to work. Unicorns might or might not be included in this solution.