# use a capture between multiple RewriteCond

Tags: mod-rewrite

given this url http://**sub**.domain.org/**sub**/other_string i need to have it rewritten to: http://newdomain/sub/...

i'm trying this rewrite, but i think i miss something in the RewriteCond.
in the second Cond can i use the capture of the first Cond?

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.org$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/%1/.*$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) /%1/$1 [nosubreq,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Sort of related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784942/reference-capture-groups-of-multiple-rewritecond-in-rewriterule . Keep in mind that the right side is either a regex, or a string literal. In neither `%1` is anything special.