# Force a URL-path for mod_rewrite's RewriteRule Substitution

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

When performing rewrites with mod_rewrite's `RewriteRule`, the substitution is evaluated and a guess made as to whether it's a URL or a file-system path, based on whether the root directory of the substitution exists on the file system. Here's the relevant section from [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> **URL-path**
>
> Note that mod_rewrite tries to guess whether you have specified a file-system path or a URL-path by checking to see if the first segment of the path exists at the root of the file-system. For example, if you specify a *Substitution* string of `/www/file.html`, then this will be treated as a URL-path *unless* a directory named `www` exists at the root or your file-system (or, in the case of using rewrites in a `.htaccess` file, relative to your document root), in which case it will be treated as a file-system path.

So my question is, how do I rewrite to a URI, where the root directory *does* exist in the file-system, but I want it to be treated as a URL?

Is there any way other than specifying the full URL? Also according to the docs:

> **Absolute URL**
>
> If an absolute URL is specified, mod_rewrite checks to see whether the hostname matches the current host. If it does, the scheme and hostname are stripped out and the resulting path is treated as a URL-path. Otherwise, an external redirect is performed for the given URL.

So I can get round it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/example.html$ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{HTTP_HOST}/var/example.html
```

Which is not ideal for readability of the code. I really want to be able to do:

```
RewriteRule ^/example.html$ /var/example.html
```

Without that being evaluated as a file-system path when `/var` exists. There doesn't seem to be a flag to force this. There is also a risk of a matching path being created later and breaking rules, which I would like to avoid without so much verbosity.

I am also aware I can solve this by putting the rules in `.htaccess` instead of the Apache config, so the search is made from the document root as described in the quote above, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Is there any other way?

**Update**

Thanks to Dusan Bajic's answer, it turns out the `[PT]` flag can help here, as hinted at in the sentence I missed off the first quote from the docs:

> If you wish other URL-mapping directives (such as Alias) to be applied to the resulting URL-path, use the [PT] flag as described below.

By using the `[PT]` flag ([docs here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt)), it will cause the substitution "to be treated as a URI instead [of a file-path]", which sounds like it should answer this question, but unfortunately there are other implications to using the `[PT]` flag:

- It implies `[L]` so no further processing of rewrite rules will occur.
- It causes URL mapping to run again, which is what it is for, and may not be desirable when simply wishing to force a substitution to be interpreted as a URL-path.

So I am leaving this question open without an accepted answer for now, as the desired solution will not have the above issues. An accepted answer will cause the substitution to be treated as a URL-path, as it would be if the root directory of the substitution did not exist in the file-system, without affecting the processing in any other way.

**Update 2**

I realised that another option to help with this, when the URL is within the document root, is to always add `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` at the start of the substitution. So it makes it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/example.html$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/var/example.html
```

This also prevents later rules that process the URL from working though, so it's similar to the `[PT]` option without causing the URL mapping to run again.

Comment: Very good question. I thought `RewriteBase` would solve that, but it's only allowed in `.htaccess` files.

Comment: You could use a rewrite cond to store `%{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{HTTP_HOST}` in a variable and then just use `%1` in your rewrite rule but that adds a full line so not sure it simplifies anything.

Comment: @Capsule Agreed, it also prevents another `RewriteCond` being used that needs to capture something for use in the rule. It really seems to me that a flag is needed to force URL context on the substitution. It would also avoid polling the file-system for every rewrite. I would even prefer to see it be the default, and the flag be needed to activate file-system paths, though of course it would break backwards compatibility.

Comment: Yeah, not sure how the cond capturing works when using multiple ones... Another good question :-)

Comment: @Capsule Captures are only available from the last `RewriteCond`.

Comment: Yes, I just read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784942/reference-capture-groups-of-multiple-rewritecond-in-rewriterule This is convoluted :-)

Comment: @Capsule It would be convoluted otherwise. It keeps it simple to only have captures available from the last match. Or what would `%1` mean? What would any of them mean? You can use all 9 captures in one match. It's straight forward this way, I think.

Comment: I like the `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` approach!

Comment: @Capsule Yes, me too, it's nice and explicit.

Answer (score 4):

You overlooked the last sentence of the quoted paragraph:

> If you wish other URL-mapping directives (such as Alias) to be applied
>   to the resulting URL-path, use the [PT] flag as described below.

It seems like it does not apply to your (very sensible btw.) question, but if you dig further into [[PT]](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt):

> The target (or substitution string) in a RewriteRule is assumed to be
>   a file path, by default. The use of the [PT] flag causes it to be
>   treated as a URI instead.

For example (if you turn on `LogLevel debug rewrite:trace6`):

```
RewriteRule ^/boo$ /opt/mock.png
```

Will log:

```
[...] init rewrite engine with requested uri /boo
[...] applying pattern '^/boo$' to uri '/boo'
[...] rewrite '/boo' -> '/opt/mock.png'
[...] local path result: /opt/mock.png
[...] go-ahead with /opt/mock.png [OK]
```

but

```
RewriteRule ^/boo$ /opt/mock.png [PT]
```

Will log:

```
[...] init rewrite engine with requested uri /boo
[...] applying pattern '^/boo$' to uri '/boo'
[...] rewrite '/boo' -> '/opt/mock.png'
[...] forcing '/opt/mock.png' to get passed through to next API URI-to-filename handler
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. The only thing troubling me is the second pass through URL processing when the rules are in the main config. I'm going to do some testing and see if that happens for all substitutions that are handled as URL-paths, or only when the `PT` flag is applied. Will update here later when I've done that.

Comment: I had a play around with this and it resolves the problem to a point. A  problem is that it implies the `[L]` flag, so it can't be used if later rules could need to run. It doesn't cause the rewrite rules to run again, as I thought it might from the docs, so no problem there. Another minor annoyance is that it does cause a re-run of the other URL processing that doesn't happen when a URL-path is specified normally. I'm really just looking for a way to force a substitution to be interpreted as a URL-path, without any other changes to the processing. I'll update the question with this new info.