# Apache Alias forbidden

Tags: angularjs, apache, vue.js, mod-rewrite, alias

I'm currently in the process of trying to launch a new version of a web platform in a subfolder so it can co-exist with the existing platform.

e.g.

https://subdomain.example.com/ <-- Current Version

https://subdomain.example.com/v3/ <-- New Version

The current version is an angularJS app and the new version is Vuejs. The platform is hosted on AWS with elastic beanstalk.

My apache config right now is

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "/var/app/current/current-app/releases/current"
        <Directory "/var/app/current/current-app/releases/current">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
         RewriteEngine On
         RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
         RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^ELB-HealthChecker.*
         RewriteRule . https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.html$ [OR]
         RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
         RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
         RewriteRule ^ - [L]
         RewriteRule ^ /index.php
        </Directory>

        Alias "/v3" "/var/app/current/new-app/v3/"
        AliasMatch "^/v3/(.*)$" "/var/app/current/new-app/v3/$1"
        <Directory "/var/app/current/new-app/v3">
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
           AllowOverride All
           Require all granted
           RewriteEngine On
           RewriteBase /
           RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
           RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^ELB-HealthChecker.*
           RewriteRule . https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

           RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
           RewriteRule . /v3/index.html [L]
        </Directory>
      </VirtualHost>
```

The new app compiles into a folder called `v3`.

Occasionally when I visit the `https://subdomain.example.com/v3/` i am presented with the new version of the web-app. Other times I'm given a 403 error.

Any time I try to go to a route that needs to be handled with the vuejs router (`v3`) directly, apache returns a 403. For example https://subdomain.example.com/v3/auth/login.

However, visiting /v3/ itself will forward me to /v3/auth/login and display the correct thing.

Another issue is that the rewrite for https is no longer functioning and allowing non-https connections.

Any help here would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you want to disable `MultiViews` when using rewrite rules.
You probably want to disable auto indexes too, so that would be `Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews`.

Since you have a rewrite rule, you could actually avoid the alias altogether and rewrite to the full path. That would make things way easier to manage.

Something like:

`RewriteRule v3.*$ /var/app/current/new-app/v3/index.html [L]`

That rule would need to live within your "main" (something in relation to your `DocumentRoot`) `Directory` directive tho as you would not access the actual v3 path per se like you do with your alias.

It's a common misconception that the rewritten part of a rewrite rule should be a valid URL, while it could just be a valid server path. There's an interesting take on this here:
[Force a URL-path for mod_rewrite's RewriteRule Substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425674/force-a-url-path-for-mod-rewrites-rewriterule-substitution)

HTH